Passing column value as a parameter to getfilesbyid() function
I don't have any background on coding as I am from medical side. I have written code to update my Google sheet data into respective patients personal doc file. I have collected all the Ids of doc files into one column and I use getfilesbyid through loop to update the details of each patient. But file passing column data as i/p parameter causes an error to occur while running the script.
This is the code I have written:
onOpen() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const menu = ui.createMenu('Create Assessment Form');
    menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs');    
    menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
    const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
        if (index === 0 || row[15]) 
            return;

        const Patientid = row[0];
        const Name = row[1];
        const Day1 = row[2];
        const Day2 = row[3];
        const Day3 = row[4];
        const Day4 = row[5];
        const Day5 = row[6];
        const Day6 = row[7];
        const Day7 = row[8];
        const Day8 = row[9];
        const Day9 = row[10];
        const Day10 = row[11];
        const templateid = row[12];
 
        const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('temlateid');

        const doc = DocumentApp.openById(googleDocTemplate.getId());
        const body = doc.getBody();    

        body.replaceText('{{Name}}', Name);
        body.replaceText('{{PatientID}}', Patientid);
        body.replaceText('{{Day1}}', Day1);
        body.replaceText('{{Day2}}', Day2);
        body.replaceText('{{Day3}}', Day3);
        body.replaceText('{{Day4}}', Day4);
        body.replaceText('{{Day5}}', Day5);
        body.replaceText('{{Day6}}', Day6);
        body.replaceText('{{Day7}}', Day7);
        body.replaceText('{{Day8}}', Day8);
        body.replaceText('{{Day9}}', Day9);
        body.replaceText('{{Day10}}', Day10);

        doc.saveAndClose();
    }); 
}

Please correct me if anything wrong and apology in advance for anything wrong due to my lack of knowledge.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Kindly provide a sample template of your document.

At first glance, you should remove the ticks before and after temlateid in DriveApp.getFileById('temlateid') and correct the misspelling so that it becomes as; DriveApp.getFileById(templateid). The ticks makes it a plain text, not a variable. There may be other problems though....

I already tried it. Removing the single quotes (tick as you mentioned), but it was not working so i tried to make it as string. Thats why.

Perhaps your templateid is incorrect because having templateid as a string is  definitely not going to work.  Just to be sure you understand row[12] is column M.

did you also change temlateid to templateid ?

Generate and Save a New Document using makeCopy
I modified your script that will generate a new Google Document based on the data that you have entered and it will also automatically save on your Google Drive.
Kindly try using the script below.
Full Modified Code:
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Create Assessment Form');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('Your_Doc_ID'); //Change with your actual Template Doc ID
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Your_Folder_ID'); //Change with your actual Google Drive Folder ID
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Replace with your Sheet Name
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0 || row[14]) return;
    const Patientid = row[0];
    const Name = row[1];
    const Day1 = row[2];
    const Day2 = row[3];
    const Day3 = row[4];
    const Day4 = row[5];
    const Day5 = row[6];
    const Day6 = row[7];
    const Day7 = row[8];
    const Day8 = row[9];
    const Day9 = row[10];
    const Day10 = row[11];
    const templateid = row[12];

    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Patient: ${row[1]}`, destinationFolder) //Document Name
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();

    body.replaceText('{{Name}}', Name);
    body.replaceText('{{PatientID}}', Patientid);
    body.replaceText('{{Day1}}', Day1);
    body.replaceText('{{Day2}}', Day2);
    body.replaceText('{{Day3}}', Day3);
    body.replaceText('{{Day4}}', Day4);
    body.replaceText('{{Day5}}', Day5);
    body.replaceText('{{Day6}}', Day6);
    body.replaceText('{{Day7}}', Day7);
    body.replaceText('{{Day8}}', Day8);
    body.replaceText('{{Day9}}', Day9);
    body.replaceText('{{Day10}}', Day10);

    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 15).setValue(url) //The row where the Document link will be stored
  })
}


Note: On line 8 and 9, make sure to replace it with your actual Document ID and Google Drive Folder ID

Output:

Few Notes:

The Document name will be based on the patient's name. You can also change it based on your preference.
Even if you run the script multiple times, once the link is generated on column O, the script will not generate a duplicate file.
The documents will be automatically saved in your drive folder.

References:

getUrl()
saveAndClose()
makeCopy(name, destination)


If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. Feel free to clarify below if this was not the result you want.

Actually i have write the same code above to generate patients basic details. Now i want to update the each document of every patient with their daily treatment updates. So i have the id of the generated documents with basic details. I want to pass it as a parameter for the function getfilebyid()

Can you provide your expected output and your template docs by editing your question above?
